# Change SQL query: Partition By

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a **TABLE**, for that TABLE I want to retrieve table data for max of DATE<01-01-2021 & max of DATE<01-01-2022.

***Table Query is:***

```
  select * from TABLE where ENTITY ID=47 order by DATE
```

***TABLE DATA:***

| AuditID | DATE | ENTITY ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 78632 | 11/14/2017 | 47 |
| 82181 | 12/12/2017 | 47 |
| 110243 | 7/6/2018 | 47 |
| 134478 | 4/24/2019 | 47 |
| 154082 | 8/19/2019 | 47 |
| 154083 | 4/3/2021 | 47 |
| 154084 | 5/3/2021 | 47 |
| 222971 | 6/3/2021 | 47 |

***Result required:***

| AuditID | DATE | ENTITY ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 154082 | 8/19/2019 | 47 |
| 222971 | 6/3/2021 | 47 |

For the above result I've used below query:

**

```
select * from TABLE where DATE =
(select max(DATE) from TABLE where DATE <DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE())-1,1,1) and ENTITY ID=47 )
OR DATE =
(select max(DATE) from TABLE where DATE < DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),1,1) and ENTITY ID=47 )
and ENTITY ID=47
```

**

But the due to performance issue for millions of records, I want to write above query using "**OVER PARTITION BY** "

Comment: Is this question about mysql or about sql-server ? They are both very different products

Comment: What is the logic exact ? from what I can see from your sample data you can just do select top 2 ... order by date desc

Comment: select top 2 * from table1 order by [date] desc [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=853cd33a5afb9e530338f16fea35d0f3)

Comment: I want to retrieve table data for max of DATE<01-01-2021 & max of DATE<01-01-2022 using 'partition by'

Comment: Why ? To get to your desired output from your sample data you don't need it. So explain why ?

Comment: I have to get  last two year comparison . Need to pick max row where date <01-01-2021 for year 2021 and max row where date <01-01-2022 for year 2022

Comment: Use 2 separate queries and UNION ALL.

Comment: Why do you think it would be more performant to use a window? Do you have an index on entityID and date?

Comment: Any other method apart from using this query                                                       
       select * from TABLE where DATE =
(select max(DATE) from TABLE where DATE <DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE())-1,1,1) and ENTITY ID=47 )
OR DATE =
(select max(DATE) from TABLE where DATE < DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),1,1) and ENTITY ID=47 )
and ENTITY ID=47

Comment: @CaiusJard index on EntityID

Comment: Have you tried outer apply ? See this [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=efb038e6cffc76f47bfe612409ced253)

Comment: @GuidoG It's subjective but personally for a top 2 I find a union all a lot more intuitive than multiple apply. YMMV.

Comment: @AaronBertrand That depends on the situation, I use them both. I do think that the union all will perform better, or am I wrong there ?

Comment: @GuidoG The apply version you've written is essentially a union all but uses syntax much less likely to be familiar to folks coming here for help, IMHO, and doesn't _add value_. As for performance, I don't know, it probably depends on other factors than just syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You can use top and union. If date needs to be calculated do it before the query. ie:

```
declare @thisYear datetime = datefromparts(year(getdate()),1,1);
declare @lastYear datetime = datefromparts(year(getdate())-1,1,1);
declare @entityId int = 47;

select * from
    (select top(1) * from myTable
    where entitiyId = @entityId and [date] < @lastYear
    order by [date] desc) t1
    union all
select * from
    (select top(1) * from myTable
    where entitiyId = @entityId and [date] < @thisYear
    order by [date] desc) t2;
```

Comment: You [can't have two `order by` clauses like that](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4aec1b44bf70160521aa298c28b733c6) though?

Comment: And you've dropped the EntityID requirement btw

Comment: @AaronBertrand, right, my bad. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure a union all would be far more efficient than those subqueries:

```
DECLARE @EntityID int = 47,
        @thisyear date = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),1,1);

SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT TOP (1) * FROM dbo.table 
  WHERE DATE < @thisyear
    AND EntityID = @EntityID
  ORDER BY DATE DESC
) AS t2021
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT TOP (1) * FROM dbo.table
  WHERE DATE < DATEADD(YEAR, -1, @thisyear)
    AND EntityID = @EntityID
  ORDER BY DATE DESC
) AS t2020;
```

If you really, really, really want to use a window function:

```
DECLARE @EntityID int = 47,
        @thisyear date = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),1,1);

; /* previous statement terminator, see sqlblog.org/cte */
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT AuditID, DATE, EntityID, y = YEAR([Date]),
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR([Date]) ORDER BY [Date] DESC)
  FROM dbo.table
  WHERE EntityID = @EntityID
    AND DATE < @thisyear
)
SELECT TOP (2) AuditID, DATE, EntityID
   FROM src 
   WHERE rn = 1 ORDER BY y DESC;
```

Comment: You've dropped the EntityID requirement.. ?

Comment: @CaiusJard Sure, that doesn't seem to be a mind-bending part of the problem the OP hasn't figured out (especially given all the sample data was for a single `EntityID`). But yes, I'll update it.

Comment: If there's one thing SO has taught me about horses and water... :D

Answer (score 0):

Though the union all from the other answers is IMHO the most easy to read and understand solution, I would still like to offer another way to write it

```
select t.*
from   table1 t
  outer apply (select top 1 [Date]
               from   table1 t2
               where  t2.[Date] < '20210101'
               order by t2.[Date] desc
              ) m21
  outer apply (select top 1 [Date]
               from   table1 t2
               where  t2.[Date] < '20220101'
               order by t2.[Date] desc
              ) m22
where  t.[Date] in (m21.[Date], m22.[Date])
and    t.EntityID = 47
```

You can see it in this [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=61d415550c2b693732c8af8f39b2ec9a)

Comment: Then I think you would want to convert those cross apply to outer apply.

Comment: @CetinBasoz My bad, I changed it